# Referencing Ant build.xml within JAR

Tags: java, ant, jar

I'm executing an ANT task using Java code, via an executable jar. I'd like to include the build.xml within the executable JAR, but can't figure out how to reference it in my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BuildLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
    logger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
    logger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
    logger.setErrorPrintStream(System.out);
    logger.setEmacsMode(true);

    ProjectHelper ph = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
    Project p = new Project();
    p.addBuildListener(logger);
    p.init();
    p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", ph);
    //File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/report.xml").toURI()); I can't do toURI on this, it throws an exception
    ph.parse(p, this.getClass().getResource("/report.xml")); //This throws a NullPointerException within ANT
    p.executeTarget("dumpandreport");
}
```

If I create a `java.io.File` object that references an external build.xml file and specify that in `ph.parse`, this works...If I try to reference a file that is packaged within the JAR, this doesn't. I have validated (via 7-ZIP) that the file `report.xml` is, in fact, in the root of the JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, disappointingly, I never did quite figure this out. You can, however, do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    ph.parse(p, getAntXML()};
    ...
}

private Object getAntXML() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report.xml");
        File f = File.createTempFile("report", "xml");
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        return f;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Nop
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Nop
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This works well enough for my purposes anyway.